# Upload is not working in custom plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin which allows for adding new video information, in which I have some other field, especially field for uploading the featured image.

I have tried several functions like media_handle_upload or wp_handle_upload but none of theme works. Every other configurations are true, regardless of max_upload_size,etc... Also I tried to upload by adding a media directly in wp-admin and it worked well.

I don't know why this is happening. The error I received is :

```
> bject(WP_Error)#1844 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["upload_error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(212) "File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

The code I am working as below:

```
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

    // Let WordPress handle the upload.
    // Remember, 'my_image_upload' is the name of our file input in our form above.
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'video_photo_url', 0 );

    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
        // There was an error uploading the image.

        var_dump($attachment_id);
        die();
    } else {
        // The image was uploaded successfully!
        var_dump($attachment_id);
        die();
    }
```

The form is as below:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
        <table class='wp-list-table widefat fixed'>


            <tr>
                <th class="ss-th-width">Upload Photo</th>
                <td><input type="file" name="video_photo_url" id="fileToUpload"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th class="ss-th-width">Video URL</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="video_url" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="ss-field-width" style="width:100%;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type='submit' name="insert" value='Save' class='button'>
    </form>
```

Hope somebody can help me on this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: add enctype="multipart/form-data" into your form tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

try to mention enctype. it tells form to post file with form. i guess it is a problem in your case

Comment: yes. it is such a carelessness of mine. It worked now. Thanks a lot. :)